# MySQL Non-monotonic query

Tags: mysql, database

Using the following database schema, find Bars which serve only beer(s) which Joe likes

```
Beers(name, manf)
Bars(name, addr, license)
Drinkers(name, addr, phone)
Likes(drinker, beer)
Sells(bar, beer, price)
Frequents(drinker, bar)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bars b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT l.beer
    FROM likes l
    WHERE l.drinker = 'joe' AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT *
        FROM sells s 
        WHERE l.beer = s.beer AND b.name = s.bar))
```

My attempt returns bars which serve beer joe likes instead of bars which only serve beers he likes.
Any help as to where I am going wrong would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

could be these bars

```
select bar 
from Sells not in (
        select  bar 
        from Sells 
        where beer  not in (select beer from likes where drinker = 'joe')
)
```

Comment: I tested this on mysql workbench and it causes syntax errors on not in